# drupal cck api: how to retrieve field-type for a particular cck field

Tags: api, drupal, cck

Suppose I have a field named 'field_myimage'.
Does cck have an api function that will allow me to retrieve the field-type (eg 'filefield') and widget (eg 'image upload') associated with this fieldname?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(content_fields() AS $field => $info){
  drupal_set_message("$field : ". $info['module']);
}
```

or you can retrieve info by other way:

```
$field = content_database_info(content_fields('field_myfield'));
```